# How to check if button hclicked and act accordingly (Django)

Tags: python, django, button, django-templates

In my first project, I am trying to do add a new line/form whenever the user presses the 'add' button.

[image]

The code I have produced is the following, and it's in the 'home.html' file:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Create Your Meal</h1>
<p>here you can select your meal and ingredients</p>
<form action="/action_page.php">
    Select quantity:
    <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5" value="0">
    Select meal
    <select name="meals">
        {% for meal in meals%}
        <option value="{{ meal }}">{{ meal }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <button onclick="">Add Meal</button>
    {% if
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

I think has something to do with the 'onclick' mouse event attribute, but I don't know how to tackle this problem.

At the moment I can only think of the following options:

1. check if the button has been clicked with an 'if' template tag inside the template (I don't know how to write this though).
2. do the check inside the view.py file (again, I don't know how to pass the argument).

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is more JavaScript related than Django.

you cannot control a click to a front-end element just using Django templatetags, you should use javascript.

Said that, let's try to do an approach (**not tested**), some adjustments may be needed.

**In your template**

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Create Your Meal</h1>
<p>here you can select your meal and ingredients</p>
<form action="/action_page.php">
    <div id="all-forms" style="float: left;">
    <div id="first-form-fields" style="float: left;">
        Select quantity:
        <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5" value="0">
        Select meal
        <select name="meals">
            {% for meal in meals%}
                <option value="{{ meal }}">{{ meal }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    <button id="button-add-meal">Add Meal</button>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

**JavaScript (I assume that jQuery is available as `$`)**

```js
$(function () {
  $("#button-add-meal").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // avoid default button behavior
    // Get first form fields html
    var fields_html = $("#first-form-fields").html();
    // TODO: reset current field values & maybe rename the fields?
    // Append the fields 
    $("#all-forms").append("<div>" + fields_html + "</div>");
  });
});
```

You can try to give a try to [django formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/) since their are built to deal with this situations and avoid some possible problems like fields naming and other stuff depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At the moment I am learning Django so I still don't know JQuery. I will try with formsets though.